# React: Redux state from mapStateToProps not updating after dispatch is called

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I dispatch an action from inside the component (i.e. a button is clicked), the state that is changed in the action is not immediately updated in the component's props. I am connecting the state and dispatch to the props through Redux's connect function. I did notice that it updates properly within the component's rendering.

---

**Game.jsx**

```
const Game = ({ playerCards, add }) => {
  const stand = () => {};

  const hit = () => {
    add(getNextCard());
    console.log(playerCards); // Outputs the old state
  };

  return (
    <div className="container--center">
      <div className="container__inner--center">
        <div className="game-wrapper">
          <div className="game-wrapper__inner">
            <Player />

            <form className="player-actions">
              <button type="button" onClick={stand}>
                Stand
              </button>
              <button type="button" onClick={hit}>
                Hit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      playerCards: state.cards.player,
    };
  },
  (dispatch) => {
    return {
      add: (card) => dispatch(addPlayerCard(card)),
    };
  }
)(Game);
```

**addPlayerCard action**

```
const addPlayerCard = (card = {}) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_PLAYER_CARD,
    card,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First state updates are asynchronous.

Second when you dispatch `add(getNextCard())` you want to update some state in the UI to be rendered again, so the new state will be available till the next re-render and it does not make any sens trying getting the new state just after the dispatch call.

So the new `playerCards` value will be printed in the UI (in the render function).